# Google cloud storage as the sole 'backend' for a static data powered application?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Can Google cloud storage be used in such an application without a proper http server (Traditional LAMP stack, GAE, etc.)?

If you're having a hard time wrapping your head around "static data powered application", think of it like a blog where you can only read the blog posts (i.e. no likes,comments or any kind of interaction) and which is managed by only one person who updates, adds or removes those blog posts.

The main concerns that I have are :

- Read-only access from JavaScript at client side
- Prevention against abuse (Does google automatically detect and ban an IP when it sends too many requests, so that the IP can't abuse bandwidth?)

I did some basic digging around the docs, but couldn't find the answer to these, possibly because not many have tried this, I guess.

Comment: Yes, you can use it like that. You can set permissions etc so the content is read only.

Comment: That's lovely, @PaulCollingwood thanks for the comment.

Comment: np. The abuse side of things, no idea however. Setting a price per day maximum would help cap the worst case.

Comment: Yeah, that's the least I can do to protect myself. The IP-ban solution will be neater though.

Answer (score 1):

The access question is already answered by Paul. You can add "read" permission to all users for your object. If you want to do so for all objects in a bucket, you can also set the default object ACL for the bucket to contain such permission.

Google does have abuse protection, but it's not designed for a specific service or resource, and the bar is pretty high given Google's global scale, so it probably won't help your specific use case.

Unfortunately you cannot set a maximum daily spending yet. The Google cloud platform team is always working on new features to help customers solve these issues, but I cannot comment on specific feature or timeline.